Postgres SELECT in form suitable for copy-paste to INSERT in psql
In psql, I'd like to SELECT a single record in a format that's suitable for copy-pasting as an INSERT in another unrelated/disconnected database with the same schema.
For example, I want to do this:
SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 1

And then be able to copy-paste the column values in a format that's suitable to paste into this:
INSERT INTO foo VALUES <paste output here>

Where the values are already appropriately quoted for insert.
The table schema is identical in the source and destination database, but there's no connection between the two (different servers that can't speak to each other).

Use the COPY command instead. It's there exactly for this purpose.

Something like this?
